# Sonos API subscription callbacks stopped

Tags: api, callback, sonos

I have perl on apache http service that's been working fine for several years to issue sonos cmds and receive callbacks.  About two weeks ago, I stopped receiving any callbacks.

- I subscribed successfully (response={}) for groupVolume, playbackMetadata, and playback events.
- I am successfully getting webhook messages from other services (e.g., Vonage) using https, so it seems the port is open to my server, and apache is successfully processing these requests.  I see no trace of any messages from the sonos api in my apache logs.
- I have no trouble issuing commands (setMute, getFavorites, getPlaybackMetadata, etc.). Only the callbacks are a problem.
- I ran the ssltools checker from digicert but found no issues.
- I can't recall making any changes to the home router config.

Does anyone else have a problem like this or know how to diagnose what's happening?

I installed WireShark but am overwhelmed with the functionality and don't know how to narrow down what I should be looking for to see if the messages are being received and blocked somehow.

Answer (score 0):

it may be unlikely, but is it possible that there isn't any usage of your integration that would result in callbacks being sent to your service? For example - if volume isn't being changed, or playback isn't happening, you won't receive events.

If that's not the case, additional information is required to debug this issue. Could you please email developer-feedback@sonos.com with the following information:

1. The name of your service/application
2. The date/time your service stopped receiving callback events. You said about two weeks ago, but could you be more specific?
3. The clientId used by your code. This is the UUID you generated when you initially created the "API Key" on developer.sonos.com. Format is xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx (note - we do not need the secret associated with this key).

With that information we should be able to determine the cause of your missing callbacks.